# secure-file-priv error when importing csv file in mysql even with the correct directory

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upload a small .csv file into my MySQL Server 8.0 using the following command:

```html
load data infile 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\inventory.csv'
into table massDepthAngle
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 rows;
```

When I check the value of secure_file_priv, the value is the same folder I am trying to upload a file from:

```html
mysql> show variables like 'secure_file_priv';
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                                          |
+ -----------------+------------------------------------------------+
| secure_file_priv | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\ |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But still, I get the "The MySQL server is running with -secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement" error.

I've tried numerous times to edit my Configuration File, but absolutely nothing has worked.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads` doesn't match `C:\ProgramData\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads`

Comment: @GuidoFaecke right that's my bad, I copied it over wrong.  They are both 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads'

Comment: Did you restart the server (mysqld) after changing the settings?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Which is why I couldn't figure out why nothing was changing.

Comment: Instead of `load data infile`, try `load data LOCAL infile`

Comment: I get the error "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access."

Comment: Take a look at `show global variables like 'local_infile';`